# How to customize ShareKit actionsheet?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sharekit

I am using ShareKit (www.getsharekit.com) to share my URL's to Twitter and Facebook. I want to be able to remove all of the additional social network it points to, but am not sure where to edit?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From ShareKit/Core/SHK.m:

```
[SHK setFavorites: (NSArray *)favs forType:(SHKShareType)type]

+ (void)setFavorites:(NSArray *)favs forType:(SHKShareType)type
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:favs forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i", SHK_FAVS_PREFIX_KEY, type]];
}
```

favs is like :

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SHKTwitter",@"SHKFacebook",@"SHKReadItLater",nil]
```

type is SHKShareType:

```
typedef enum 
{
    SHKShareTypeUndefined,
    SHKShareTypeURL,
    SHKShareTypeText,
    SHKShareTypeImage,
    SHKShareTypeFile
} SHKShareType;
```

Answer (score 49):

in SHK.m find this method

```
+ (NSArray *)favoriteSharersForType:(SHKShareType)type
```

and change

```
switch (type) 
    {
        case SHKShareTypeURL:
            favoriteSharers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SHKTwitter",@"SHKFacebook",@"SHKReadItLater",nil];
            break;

        case SHKShareTypeImage:
            favoriteSharers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SHKTwitter",@"SHKFacebook",@"SHKReadItLater",nil];
            break;

        case SHKShareTypeText:
            favoriteSharers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SHKTwitter",@"SHKFacebook",@"SHKReadItLater",nil];
            break;

        case SHKShareTypeFile:
            favoriteSharers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SHKTwitter",@"SHKFacebook",@"SHKReadItLater",nil];
            break;
```

to the following for each instance of the switch statement:

```
favoriteSharers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SHKFacebook", nil];
```

or what ever other options you want to support (ie if you only want twitter and facebook add @"SHKTwitter", to the array)

that will eliminate the other options but the action sheet that displays the options wont reflect the change and it will still give the more option, which we also need to disable.

So to do that go to SHKActionSheet.m

in this method you can change the title from "Share" to something more specific (this part is optional) ie "Share with Facebook and Twitter"

```
+ (SHKActionSheet *)actionSheetForType:(SHKShareType)type
```

change

```
SHKActionSheet *as = [[SHKActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:SHKLocalizedString(@"PUT YOUR NEW TITLE HERE")
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                    destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
as.item = [[[SHKItem alloc] init] autorelease];
as.item.shareType = type;
```

than in that same method, delete this line

```
    // Add More button
[as addButtonWithTitle:SHKLocalizedString(@"More...")];
```

that will remove the more button but now the code will now confuse the more button with the cancel button, so to fix that, go to this method:

```
- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated
```

and delete the following else if statement

```
// More
else if (buttonIndex == sharers.count)
{
    SHKShareMenu *shareMenu = [[SHKCustomShareMenu alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    shareMenu.item = item;
    [[SHK currentHelper] showViewController:shareMenu];
    [shareMenu release];
}
```

what this method is susposted to do is take the button that is normally the more button and open the more options.  So by deleting it the code has no associated action with the cancel button so it just closes and release the action sheet, effectively creating a cancel button

Comment: Wish I could give you 10 upvotes for such a thorough explanation. This is exactly what I needed - thanks!

Comment: What a great answer. Best thing I've seen on SO in a while... and by someone with low rep like me!

Answer (score 7):

The new way to do this with latest version of ShareKit 2.0 is to overwrite the following methods in your SHKConfigurator (extending DefaultSHKConfigurator.m)

```
// SHKActionSheet settings
- (NSNumber*)showActionSheetMoreButton {
    return [NSNumber numberWithBool:true];// Setting this to true will show More... button in SHKActionSheet, setting to false will leave the button out.
}

/*
 Favorite Sharers
 ----------------
 These values are used to define the default favorite sharers appearing on ShareKit's action sheet.
 */
- (NSArray*)defaultFavoriteURLSharers {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SHKTwitter",@"SHKFacebook", @"SHKReadItLater", nil];
}
- (NSArray*)defaultFavoriteImageSharers {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SHKMail",@"SHKFacebook", @"SHKCopy", nil];
}
- (NSArray*)defaultFavoriteTextSharers {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SHKMail",@"SHKTwitter",@"SHKFacebook", nil];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See: http://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/issues/closed#issue/30

Answer (score 2):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371661/sharekit-changes) on the other thread with more thorough explanation.

It is now easily configurable without changing ShareKit's code, if you use [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit)

<del>Basically, if you use only Facebook and Twitter, it is easier not to mess with ShareKit's code. You can easily 
create your own UIActionSheet with two buttons, and call [ShareKit's convenience share](http://www.getsharekit.com/docs/#specific-service) methods.</del>

Comment: wonder why down vote? With "mess with ShareKit's code" I mean to customize ShareKit's code in your app (hiding More button), when it is not necessary. This will earn you additional work, if you want to upgrade to newer version of ShareKit. You can achieve the same using ShareKit's sharers convenience methods directly with classic standard UIActionSheet.

Answer (score 2):

For the unwanted services not to appear on the action sheet you can simply remove the respective sharer services classes from the project.

Go to project--> Sharers --> Services --> select the .h and .m files of the respective service and delete it.

For example Facebook option can be removed by deleting SHKFacebook.h and SHKFacebook.m.

Note: You will have to check the class import to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to edit "SHKSharers.plist" and keep the services you need.