# ShareKit 2.0: how to add a custom NON-SHARE item in action sheet?

Tags: uiactionsheet, sharekit

I am using ShareKit in one of my projects, and there is an option to add something to favourites, other than share it, it is an option in ShareKit's action sheet, looks like I can only populate 'shares', how do I add my custom item to its action sheet and associate a selector to it or get a callback for when its tapped?

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to have a special kind of SHKItem and need to pick favourite sharers for it, or do you want to add a button with action completely unrelated to sharekit?

Comment: I want to add a button with action completely unrelated to sharekit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to create SHKActionSheet subclass and override

```
+ (SHKActionSheet *)actionSheetForType:(SHKShareType)type;
- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Do not forget to set your subclass in configurator's `- (Class)SHKActionSheetSubclass` config method. This way you can call sharekit the same way as in the demo app, I mean you can create action sheet like this:

```
SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];
```

Another possibility is to create standard UIActionSheet and call each sharer's convenience methods. See the code in my [other answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371661/sharekit-changes/8238631#8238631). This is appropriate if you have only fixed number of sharers - when you do not need to use SHKShareMenu.